# Basic campsites in Black Forest (Schwarzwald)

Tags: germany, camping, rural

I'm hoping to find a cheap basic campsite in the Black Forest for a family of four. Not fussed about flash facilities, electric hook up etc. Composting toilet and peaceful location would suit us just fine! Near a lake or river would be a bonus. The cheaper the better.  Does anyone have any good ideas / local knowledge they could share?  Thanks

Comment: If you're planning a hiking/trekking/backpacking trip, you might be interested in [Outdoors.SE] SE.

Comment: Here's a list - I didn't feel like typing out all the sites: https://www.eurocampings.co.uk/campsite/search/regionID/870/#sort=price_summer2adultsCaravan%20asc